# GMAC+PHY in Allwinner R40

Tags: c, embedded, ethernet

I'm trying to write embedded bare-metal GMAC and PHY drivers to be able to use ethernet on Allwinner R40. I've configured both: GMAC and PHY (Realtek rtl8211) but I suspect I missed something or did it wrong. For now I'm able to turn the LED on the ethernet connector. The RGMII status register tells that RGMII link is set properly. 
I've created proper list of RX and TX descriptors for GMAC and passed their addresses to GMAC.

The problem is that I cannot send or receive anything at the moment. After I set proper bits to start DMA for TX the whole list of descriptors is untouched. I mean if GMAC would work then at least one TX descriptor should be changed, but it is not. There is bit number 31 in the first descriptor word indicating that this descriptor belongs to TX DMA. I set it according to the doc. GMAC DMA should clear this bit when traversing the descriptor list. But it is not cleared.

Second thing - PHY returns in PHYSR (17.10) that ethernet link is not ok.
Is it possible that GMAC is not traversing descriptor list because PHY reports that link is not ok? If not what else can cause that GMAC is not starting any transfers?

Comment: You can check some simple reference implementation, f.e. u-boot net driver for allwinner r40. This will help you to understand the difference between working version and yours. I don't think that somebody here will help you, because there might be a plenty of reasons why this is not working. Good luck in your investigation.

Comment: @AlexHoppus:  Strange thing - when I run this driver from u-boot it is working fine. The difference is that in case of bare-metal I placed my driver in SRAM, but in case of uboot in DRAM. Is it possible that DMA cannot work with SRAM, but is working fine with DRAM? Or maybe uboot configures some part of R40 but I'm not doing it?